# in mdx, want to use use one or another measure in calculation depending on dimension values

Tags: mdx, iccube

I want to calculate sometHing depending on dimension values : I tried

```
WITH 
  CALCULATED MEMBER [Measures].[Switch] AS 
    IIF
    (
      [Ambu].[Ambu].CurrentMember IS [Ambu].[Ambu].[Non Ambulatoire]
     ,[Measures].[Nombre de Journées]
     ,(
        [Measures].[NbSejours]
       ,[Ambu].[Ambu].[Ambulatoire]
      )
    ) 
  MEMBER result AS 
    [Measures].[RecettesT2a] / [Measures].[Switch] 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[RecettesT2a]
   ,[Measures].[Switch]
   ,result
   ,[Measures].[NbSejours]
   ,[Measures].[Nombre de Journées]
  } ON 0
 ,[Ambu].[Ambu] ON 1
 --[Classification GHM].[Recours] on 1
FROM [Cube];
```

In fact, if Ambu is Ambu, I want to divide RecettesT2a by NbSejours, and if Ambu is Non Ambu, I want to divide RecettesT2a by [Nombre de Journées]...

This result is Ok when Ambu is used on Axis 1, But if I want to use another dimension as Axis 1 (eg [Classification GHM].[Recours]), it does not work... [Measures].[Switch] is not calculated correctly...

Comment: the function `CURRENTMEMBER` used here `[Ambu].[Ambu].CurrentMember` means that this condition `[Ambu].[Ambu].CurrentMember IS [Ambu].[Ambu].[Non Ambulatoire]` will only make sense if the dimension `[Ambu]` is in context i.e. used in one of the axes

Comment: if you use another dimension, apart from `[Ambu].[Ambu]`, what should the result be? should it be `[Measures].[Nombre de Journées]` or should it be `(
        [Measures].[NbSejours]
       ,[Ambu].[Ambu].[Ambulatoire]
      )` ?

Comment: Ok, so, if I understand well, there's no solution for me this way...  I need to add a column in the fact table (and a new measure) that has already the different values regarding their Ambu/Non Ambu properties.

Comment: - I added an attempted answer below...

Answer (score 1):

We don't know what you require when `Ambu` is out of context.

So you have two options depending on what you want:

```
WITH 
  CALCULATED MEMBER [Measures].[Switch] AS 
    IIF
    (
        [Ambu].[Ambu].CurrentMember IS [Ambu].[Ambu].[Non Ambulatoire]
      OR 
        isAll([Ambu].[Ambu].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Nombre de Journées]
     ,(
        [Measures].[NbSejours]
       ,[Ambu].[Ambu].[Ambulatoire]
      )
    ) 
...
...
```

or this:

```
WITH 
  CALCULATED MEMBER [Measures].[Switch] AS 
    IIF
    (
        [Ambu].[Ambu].CurrentMember IS [Ambu].[Ambu].[Non Ambulatoire]
      OR 
        NOT isAll([Ambu].[Ambu].CurrentMember)
     ,[Measures].[Nombre de Journées]
     ,(
        [Measures].[NbSejours]
       ,[Ambu].[Ambu].[Ambulatoire]
      )
    ) 
...
...
```

Comment: in icCube we've the isAll function for members ( https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/IsAll.php )

Comment: @ic3 that is a very handy function - I've edited my attempt